# I'm trying to make the users audio downloadable but having issues

Tags: javascript, html, audio, blob, webapi

I'm trying to make an audio editor but can't seem to get audio value. I've tried document.getElementById("audio).value and document.getElementById("audio").data but both return undefined

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="file" type="file">
    <button id="save" onclick="save()">Save</button>
</body>
<script>
    var audio;
document.getElementById("file").addEventListener("change",function(e){
    var read=new FileReader()
    read.onload=function(){
        var aud=document.createElement("audio")
        aud.id="audio"
        aud.src=read.result
        document.body.appendChild(aud)
        aud.play()
        
    }
   
    
    read.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("file").files[0])
    
})
function save(){
var aud=document.getElementById("audio").value
console.log(aud)
var a=document.createElement("a")
a.href=aud
a.download="test.mp3"
document.body.appendChild(a)
a.click()
}
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result is undefined because the audio doesn't has a attribute called value instead of value use src

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="file" type="file">
    <button id="save" onclick="save(event)">Save</button>
</body>
<script>
    var audio;
document.getElementById("file").addEventListener("change",function(e){
    var read=new FileReader()
    read.onload=function(){
        var aud=document.createElement("audio")
        aud.id="audio"
        aud.src=read.result
        document.body.appendChild(aud)
        aud.play()
        
    }
   
    
    read.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("file").files[0])
    
})
function save(e){
    var aud=document.getElementById("audio").src;
    var a=document.createElement("a")
    a.href=aud
    a.download="test.mp3"
    document.body.appendChild(a)
    a.click()
}
</script>
</html>
 Run code snippet
```

If You use it the audio gonna be downloadable!

Comment: would that be the edited version?

Comment: Yes Just change the `.value` by `.src`

Comment: Don't try to download this in stack overflow code snipped it not gonna work try this in your code editor.